# DOM: Finding the current scroll context of an html element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's say I have the following document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="scrollcontainer">
    ...
    <div class="content"></div>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

And `.scrollcontainer` is a scrollable `div`:

```
.scrollcontainer {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Is there any way to find `.scrollcontainer` as the current "scroll context" (a.k.a. the parent scrollable element) for `.content`?

I'm looking something like:

```
// Should return the element `.scrollcontainer` in this example
document.querySelector('.content').scrollContext;
```

If there is a ancestor element with an `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto`, then it would be that element. Otherwise the body/html (depending on the browser).

Of course I could just add a data-attribute (e.g. `data-scrollcontext`) to every scroll context and then find the closest parent with that attribute. But I'm curious to see if something like that is implemented in the DOM Api.

Comment: What do you mean by `scroll context` ?

Comment: The parent scrollable element. If there is a ancestor element with an `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto`, then it would be that. Otherwise the body/html (depending on the browser).

Answer (score 1):

There is no DOM API to find out the scrollable container. As here the difintion "scrollable" is missleading - should it be considered only by the css property , like `overflow: scroll`, even when it is not right now scrollable, or the css property plus the "scrollHeight > offsetHeight".

You can create a custom function, which traverses the ancestors and checks the CSS properties, *or you can implement any other logic here*.